# GARAGEBAND: Cannot listen while recording. Tried it all still nothing

Tags: monitoring, audio-recording

Ok guys i'm literally having a breakdown right now. I just don't listen back my voice or guitar while I'm recording on both logic & GarageBand. I simplified the setting by removing my audio interface & I cant even hear my voice through the built-in microphone.

I have :

1. Macbook-system preferences-outpout:internal speakers & input:internal microphone
2. Garageband-preferences-audio/midi-output device:built-in input & input device: built-in microphone
3. Monitoring button at the track I want is on. I had some great ideas I just wanted to put down quickly.

HELP SERIOUSLY.

Oh not sure if it matters but i'm currently creating a TimeMachine backup on a hard drive.

Comment: But what does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 0):

Since Garageband is a commercial application for the recording of audio I'm sure that they would be able to help you get this sorted out. See for example the help online for "[GarageBand for Mac: Turn on input monitoring for audio tracks](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24927?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)" Recording using one input into two applications might be a tall order.

If you are simply trying to test whether your audio system can record and output at the same time you can use some audio applications. I can't help you with Mac, but on a Linux machine we have available for example the command

```
arecord -f dat | aplay
```

that will play back immediately all mike input.